# What's the actual reasoning behind iterator categorization in STL?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

> For reasons of efficiency it's not possible to have every container work with every generic algorithm  --  STL Tutorial and Reference Guide.

So i'm learning about STL and i was reading the mentioned book and trying simultaneously to see the justification behind this categorization of iterators, the book doesn't actually go beyond the quotes in explaining the why behind this categorization.

I understand that some generic algorithms requires certain abilities from their containers (for example random access for sort algorithms) so clearly not all containers can be all plugged in all generic algorithms for efficiency reasoning.

but this answer isn't much sufficient and it seems to me like it's only one aspect of this decision design, before reading the section i thought about the categorization as more of a safety belt (because of the naming...) but this aspect is not even mentioned in the book, all in all the book doesn't go much in details about this design decision ,if you can, could you please go in much detail about the why behind this ?

Comment: If I understand your intent, you are asking why someone came up with these categories then designed containers and algorithms for them? (Rather than, say, why someone looked at the containers and algorithms and organized them into these categories?)

Comment: I don't see how RandomAccessIterator seems to be "safety belt" for you? all it does is saying it support random access.

Comment: not specifically `random_access` iterator , but the splitting of the power  or operations supported for each iterator will decide what each algorithm can do ? if it's read-only then it can  use `input` iterator  , that's why i though about it as a safety thing?

Comment: Do you know what all the iterator categories are, and what their properties and requirements are? Do you know what all the containers in the C++ library are, what each one's properties are, and how they work? If not, you won't understand anyone's answer, so your first step will be to learn these fundamentals. If you do, then you should be able to figure out the answer yourself; consider, for example, how exactly would you implement a random access iterator for a `std::list` in a way that makes any kind of a sense.

Comment: @onehundredquestionsguy *"but the splitting of the power or operations supported for each iterator will decide what each algorithm can do"* -- I don't know what design decisions were made, but if this was one then it strikes me as a poor one, as one should not let arbitrary decisions (the "splitting") limit algorithms.

Comment: I suspect that the reason the book does not go into as much detail as you would like is that you are making more out of this than there is, seeing things that others do not. Maybe it would be a good idea for you to expand "because of the naming" into a full paragraph so that others can see what you see.

Comment: what i meant by "because of the naming" is for example `input` and `output` iterators seems to me a good synonym to `read-only` `write-only` permissions and thus a restriction on what some algorithms can do , maybe i'm wrong , but this is what i concluded , i didn't write a lot of c++ code (i write c) so maybe i don't see what people that did program a lot of c++ see, that's why i asked a question here , to get an expert point of view.

Comment: @onehundredquestionsguy I meant expand into a full paragraph **in the question**. Information in comments is transitory and not part of the question. When you do so, perhaps you could add some justification for "input" being a good synonym for "read-only" (or "input-only") instead of "read-allowed"? What justifies tacking on "only"? (And how would you explain iterators that are both input iterators and output iterators? Such as vector iterators?)

Comment: @onehundredquestionsguy -- `input` iterators are not read-only. They are iterators that support input. A random access iterator is an input iterator, and it's also an output iterator: you can read through it and you can write through it. An algorithm that takes an input iterator promises to only use that iterator for reading. That doesn't mean that the iterator has to be read-only.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but algorithms don't apply to **containers**; they apply to **ranges**. Containers are one way of managing ranges, and probably the most common, but they are not the only way. An input stream from the console can be treated as a range, and passed as input to an algorithm, but it it not a container.

Comment: @PeteBecker no actually that's a extremely valuable insight , thank you, could you please recommend some good books or resources , i'm studying now "stl toturial and reference " and it doesn't go into much details in my opinion ? thanks in advance

Comment: The cppreference website is a good C++ reference.  It has an explanatory page on [iterator categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator).

Comment: @onehundredquestionsguy Since you are curious about references: Have you checked the publication year of your book? Is it 1996? The era of STL was something like 1994-1998, and anything based on STL (as opposed to the C++ standard library) is ancient with respect to computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The justification for the categorization of iterators is that they are useful. The categories are not restrictions or "safety", not limitations on what can be. They are descriptions and an organization of what exists. Algorithms first, iterator categories second.

If someone creates a new container, the iterator of that container can be analyzed to see in which categories it fits. That is enough to know which algorithms will work with the new container. There is no need to analyze each  algorithm individually.

For example, a "for_each" algorithm requires an "input iterator". If the iterator of the hypothetical new container is an input iterator, then "for_each" can be used with that container. There is no need for the documentation of the new container to acknowledge the existence of "for_each", much less analyze the algorithm to see if it works. The container documentation merely has to state that the iterator is an input iterator, and users may deduce that "for_each" can be used with the container.

*Why does "for_each" require an input iterator? Because the algorithm needs to make a single pass of the container and extract values from the container. That functionality is guaranteed by an input iterator, and not guaranteed by more basic iterator categories. It is unlikely that someone started implementing "for_each" by saying "assume an input iterator". Rather, the starting point should have been the needed functionality. After the initial implementation, there should have been an optimization pass. After the implementation was finalized, it could be analyzed and then the iterator requirement established – at the end, not the beginning.*

Similarly, does the new container work with searching? There is no need to analyze the search algorithm, only to look up that searching requires a forward iterator. If the new iterators are forward iterators, then the search algorithm can be used with the new container. Otherwise, it cannot.

The result is a simpler experience for documentation writing because the number of iterator types is much smaller than the number of algorithms that exist or will be created in the future. Documenting which iterator types are supported is simpler and more modular than creating a list of supported algorithms.